# Best way to realize multiple shipments in one Shopware cart?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have build a marketplace with Shopware 6 where every vendor has their own logistics and warehouse. I want to allow customers to order from multiple vendors in one cart.
What is the smartest way to structure this?
Should I put all CartItems from one Vendor in a CartItem of type Container? Did anyone every do that? I mean there is this container CartItem so it just makes sense, when you use it in a way like that, or?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Shopware 6 has been designed with multiple deliveries per order being a possibility. However it has not yet been implemented fully. Currently it is expected that there is one delivery per order by default, hence why you will often find template references like `order.deliveries.first()` and such.

For now you'll have to implement the handling of multiple deliveries yourself.

After an order has been placed you can update an order to be split into multiple deliveries:

```php
$order = [
    [
        'id' => $orderId,
        'deliveries' => [
            [
                'stateId' => $stateId,
                'shippingMethodId' => $firstShippingMethodId,
                'shippingCosts' => new CalculatedPrice(10, 10, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()),
                'shippingDateEarliest' => date(\DATE_ISO8601),
                'shippingDateLatest' => date(\DATE_ISO8601),
                'shippingOrderAddressId' => $shippingOrderAddressId,
                'positions' => [
                    [
                        'price' => new CalculatedPrice(10, 10, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()),
                        'orderLineItemId' => $firstOrderLineItemId,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'stateId' => $stateId,
                'shippingMethodId' => $secondShippingMethodId,
                'shippingCosts' => new CalculatedPrice(10, 10, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()),
                'shippingDateEarliest' => date(\DATE_ISO8601),
                'shippingDateLatest' => date(\DATE_ISO8601),
                'shippingOrderAddressId' => $shippingOrderAddressId,
                'positions' => [
                    [
                        'price' => new CalculatedPrice(10, 10, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()),
                        'orderLineItemId' => $secondOrderLineItemId,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$this->orderRepository->update($order, $context);
```

If you need to split the deliveries before the order has been placed, during the checkout, you may want to [register a custom cart processor](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-processor-collector).

```xml
<service id="My\CustomPlugin\Checkout\Cart\Delivery\DeliveryProcessor">
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Delivery\DeliveryBuilder"/>
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Delivery\DeliveryCalculator"/>
    <argument type="service" id="shipping_method.repository"/>

    <!-- priority -5001 so it runs after the original delivery processor -->
    <tag name="shopware.cart.processor" priority="-5001"/>
</service>
```

Have a look at the original [`DeliveryProcessor`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/a1a3da3dcc01e1de18c7de8a8ae84f8ca34b8055/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/Delivery/DeliveryProcessor.php#L101) for reference. In the `process` method you could then split the original delivery into a collection of multiple delivers and set them to the cart.